# Conjugacy classes in a subgroup of symmetric group

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, symmetric-groups

Let $H=\langle (12)(34),(456)\rangle\cong S_4$ be a subgroup of $S_6$. It is known that there are five conjugacy classes in $S_4$ and the representatives are $(1), (12), (12)(34), (123), (1234)$.

I want to find out the five representatives of conjugacy classes of $H$. If I just look at the orders of the elements, it is hard for me to determine the elements corresponding to $(12)$ and $(12)(34)$, since both two elements have order $2$ in $S_4$. Is there any way to produce the representatives without writing out all $24$ elements of $H$?

Comment: The image of $(456)$ under the isomorphism must be a $3$-cycle. The image of $(12)(34)$ cannot be a product of two transpositions, because then the generating set would be mapped into $A_4$ and would not generate $S_4$. So the conjugacy class of $(12)(34)$ in $H$ is "like" that of $(12)$ in $S_4$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have $S_4$ acting naturally on $\{3,4,5,6\}$ with odd permutations containing the cycle $(1,2)$ so the representatives $[1,(12),(12)(34),(123),(1234)]$ in the natural representation on $\{1,2,3,4\}$ become
$$[1,(12)(34),(34)(56),(345),(12)(3456)]$$

Comment: Thanks. So, in this case, we use $S_4\cong\langle(34),(456)\rangle$. But if such method can also apply to subgroups like $H'=\langle(12)(34)(56),(123)(456)\rangle\cong S_4$ and $H''=\langle(12)(34), (135)(246)\rangle\cong S_4$?

Comment: That's a new question - I have answered the question you asked.

Answer (score 0):

Let $f:G\to G'$ be a  isomorphism and let $\operatorname{Cl_G(a) }=\{gag^{-1}:g\in G\}$.Then $f(\operatorname{Cl_G(a) }) =\operatorname{Cl_{G^{'}}(f(a)) }$

---

$H$ have exactly $5$ conjuagacy classes and corresponding representatives are $$f[(1)], f[(12) ],f[(12)(34)], f[(123)], f[(1234)]$$ where $f:S_4\to H$ is an isomorphism.

Comment: Presumably, the point of the question is whether there is a way to find the conjugacy classes *without* having to find an explicit isomorphism...

Comment: To find an isomorphism, we don't need to find the image of all $24$ elements. Find the generators and maps them to generators.

Comment: Which is still *finding an explicit isomorphism*. So your response is not an answer to my comment; it just misses the point again. And "**the** generators" is a misnomer. $S_4$ has multiple sets of generators. It's not like the choice is unique.

Comment: "Is there any way to produce the representatives without writing out all 24 elements of H?" This is the original question. Listing 24 elements and finding an explicit isomorphism is totally different. Isn't it?

Comment: You are proposing what amounts to the same amount of work, just hiding some of it in different computations. It is disingenuous.